# Is there a portable (C++ standard) way to compute the previous aligned pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Given `alignas(N) char buffer[N];` and a `char* p` between [`&buffer[0]`, `&buffer[N-1]`], can I obtain a pointer to `buffer[0]` by using `p` and `N`?

```cpp
char* previous_aligned_pointer(char* ptr, size_t align) {
   // how?
}

int main() {
  constexpr int N = 32;
  alignas(N) char buffer[N];
  assert(previous_aligned_pointer(&buffer[rand() % N], N) == &buffer[0]);
}
```

I'd like to do it in portable C++ (if possible), so something like casting a pointer to `uintptr_t` and then performing arithmetic on it may not be used.

Comment: Do you want this to work even if you do `alignas(N) char buffer[N * 2];` and `&buffer[rand() % (N * 2)]` or will the buffer size always be less than the alignment?

Comment: I'd be curious about to the use case for such a function. Can you share the problem that you expect this function to solve?

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem.  What are you actually trying to solve where you would need this?

Answer (score 5):

There is a standard library function to get the **next** aligned pointer. It's called `std::align`. You could then subtract the alignment to get the previous one.

In general that may do pointer arithmetic beyond the buffer in which case the subtraction would technically be UB. If that's a concern, then you could avoid the UB if you can allocate extra space in the buffer such that the next aligned pointer is always within the buffer.

Only other way is to implement it yourself which would have to rely on conversion to integer type which relies on implementation dependent unguaranteed behaviour. In conclusion: No, I don't think there's a general strictly standard conforming solution.

---

However, for your example case, there's no problem. The next aligned address is pointer past the end, so it's fine to subtract N to get the address to beginning of the buffer.

Comment: What if you happen pass `&buffer[0]` to `std::align`? Would that return `&buffer[0]` back, in which case the subtraction would be incorrect?

Comment: But you're passing the bigger `space` argument than it should be to `std::align`. And the resulting pointer is pointing out of buffer.

Comment: @eerorika Then I think, for this solution to work, this case has to be handled. But I don't think you can know where the buffer starts, as finding that out is the primary goal. It's a nice lead though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Finding out where buffer starts is unsolvable.

Comment: @eerorika I agree, but did I misunderstand the question or isn't that exactly equivalent to what the question is asking for? To find `&buffer[0]`.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  `std::align` only goes forward into the buffer space to find an aligned address.  The OP says the have a pointer already in the buffer space, and want to find the start of that space.

Comment: If `std::align` does nothing, then either there wasn't enough space (which I don't think is a problem in this case) or the pointer is already aligned. So if it does nothing you know you're already looking at `buffer[0]` (since it's the only already aligned address) so you don't need to subtract anything.

Comment: In this particular case, the pointer resulting from `std::align` will point past-the-end of the buffer. That is still a valid (albeit non-dereferencable) pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: What if you call `std::align` on `p+1` instead?  If `p` was definitely within the buffer (not past-the-end) then this should, intuitively at least, always return a pointer to past-the-end, and then you can unconditionally subtract `N`.

Comment: @numzero Yeah, the example case works fine.

Comment: @NateEldredge That may help, but there is still the problem of passing the `space` argument, which from my understanding must be a number of bytes that are addressable by and after `p`, in other words the space between `p` and the end of the buffer. This implies you already know the end of the buffer. I'm not sure what the consequences of lying about `space` are, but if its too low the function won't give the right result, and if its too high it is probably UB.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Technically standard requires `ptr represents the address of contiguous storage of at least space bytes`. You could avoid that problem by calling it with `space` of 1 and incrementally again until you find the next alignment or `space` reaches `N` in which case the original pointer is aligned. It's silly, but it should work.

Comment: @eerorika I can't see anything functionally wrong with that approach. I think that would work.